# wordpress blog displaying blank pages

Tags: htaccess

i have wordpress blog under my main site like following

```
-root (mainsite)
  -blog
```

i have placed `.htaccess` file to redirect my index.html page to index.php, .htaccess file have following code

```
Redirect 303 /index.html  http://mysite.com/index.php
```

but after placing this file, my blog site stopped working, none of my blog page are working, it displays blank page, i cant even access admin panel.

i have removed .htaccess file from root folder, but not able to access blog site.

do anyone knows how to overcome this problme??

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. Perhaps you need to clear your cache or maybe your server takes a while to respond to a changed .htaccess file. (What web host are you using?)

Is there another .htaccess file in the WP folder which might have been modified? Or maybe you've made other changes???

By the way, why are you using a 303 redirect instead of a 301? And why not just redirect to http://mysite.com without the index.php and then set the `DirectoryIndex` directive?

Comment: yes, my blog folder(one with wordpress installation) has .htaccess file with following content, `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing every single `.htaccess` file resident on your Wordpress installation directory (renaming would do), hit Ctrl+F5 and wait for a few minutes and try again.
If the problem still persists try turning the debug mode on by changing `WP_DEBUG` constant to `true` in `wp-config.php`.
There ought to be some messages indicating the source of the problem.